# Zero-dimensional ring having no idempotent or nilpotent ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, idempotents

> Is there a ring $R$ with zero Krull-dimension such that $R$ has neither   nonzero idempotent nor nilpotent ideals?

I know that this ring could not be Noetherian, because if this is so, then $R$ would be Artinian and hence, the Jacobson radical would be nilpotent. (Of course, this is a contradiction if the Jacobson radical is non-zero.)

Comment: Presumably you also want $R$ to not be a field?

Comment: $R$ is always nonzero idempotent, so I guess you mean to exclude that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If $R$ is zero-dimensional then $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is totally disconnected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786503/specr-hausdorff-and-totally-disconnected)  Since idempotent elements of $R$ correspond to clopen subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, this means that if $R$ has no nontrivial idempotent ideals, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a point.  This means that $R$ has a unique prime ideal, which is equal to its nilradical.  If $R$ has no nontrivial nilpotent ideals, this means the nilradical is $0$.  Thus $0$ is the unique prime ideal of $R$ and in particular is maximal, which means $R$ is a field.

Comment: How do we deduce from "$R$ has no nilpotent ideals" that $R$ has zero nilradical?

Comment: If $r\in R$ is a nonzero nilpotent, then $(r)$ is a nonzero nilpotent ideal.